# iOS Auto Layout reseting all my image positions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I have one view controller for my whole program and my program consists of moving images. The problem lies when one taps an a iAd banner it seems to call auto layout and so what auto layout does is it automatically lays out my images as I had them set up in my story board how do I avoid this from happening? Now I understand that if I uncheck Auto layout the problem will get fixed but the thing is I want to stick with auto layout for resizing when detecting a 4 inch screen

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are moving your images by setting their `frame` properties. Don't do this under Autolayout; the frame will be reset to the constraints value as soon as another layout pass occurs.

You need to alter the positions of your subviews by editing the constraints instead, either by changing the `constant` property or by removing and replacing whole constraints.

Comment: I removed all my constraints within my moving images but as another layout pass occurs it still moves them I will now try messing with the constant property

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself, first foray into auto layout after shunning it for ages in favour of iOS 5 support. This page helped me solve the issue: http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/

In viewDidLoad I ended up calling this:

```
for( NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in self.view.constraints )
{
    [self.view removeConstraint: constraint];
}

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewToCenter
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:center.x]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewToCenter
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:center.y]];
```

Basically it removes any previously set constraints (because I update them regularly with new centering constraints) and then it adds in new constraints to center it at the correct location. So I've got this self.viewToCenter which gets its offset from the top left of self.view set by the above code.